Given that $|z| = 1$, let the conjugate of $z$ be $p$. What is the minimum and maximum value of $|z^5 + p^3 + 6z| - 2|z^4 + 1|$.
Given that $|z| = 1$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and let the conjugate of $z$ be $p$. What is the minimum and maximum value of $|z^{5} + p^{3} + 6z| - 2|z^{4} + 1|$.
My attempt
I tried it by taking $z$ out of the first modulus. $|z||z^{4} + p^{3}z^{-1} + 6|$ which will give $|z^{} + p^{4} + 6|$ as for a unimodular complex number its conjugate $p = z^{-1}$.
Similarly,taking $z^{2}$ out, we can get $|z^{2}||z^{4} + p^{2}|$, which will equal $|z^{4} + p^{2}|\times 1$ as $|z^{2}| = 1$.
Now, I converted it to $z = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ form and the value will equal $2(2\cos^{4}(\theta) - 4\cos^{2}(\theta) + 3)$. Now how to minimize and maximie this one to get the answer
Or is there any other approach.
Thank you

$$A=|z^{5} + \overline{z}^{3} + 6z| - 2|z^{4} + 1|$$
$$=|z||z^4+\overline{z}^{4}+6|-2|z^2||z^2+\overline{z}^{2}|$$
$$=1\cdot|((z+\overline{z})^2-2)^2+4|-2\cdot1\cdot|(z+\overline{z})^2-2|$$
$$=|((2\cos\theta)^2-2)^2+4|-2|(2\cos\theta)^2-2|$$
$$=4(2\cos^2\theta-1)^2+4-4|2\cos^2\theta-1|$$
$$=4(\cos^22\theta-|\cos2\theta|+1)$$
Now $t=|\cos2\theta|\in[0,1]$, therefore
$$A=4(t^2-t+1)\in[3,4]$$

You might have stopped after the second line where you got to $|4u^2+4|-2|2u|$ with $2u=z^2+z^{-2}=2\cos(2\theta)$ without going around to single degree expressions and then back to double degree.

I see that now. Thanks.
